# Drawing multiple cards from the hat. The probability of winning depend on the number of cards and rounds

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, problem-solving

Let's say $M$ people play the game:

Player $i$ has $n_i$ cards with his name where $1\le i\le M$

All cards put in the hat. Then a card is randomly drawn from the hat. The owner of the card is the winner. All winner cards are removed from the hat. Everything is repeating in the next round, but there are no last round winner cards.

So, the question is

**What is the probability that a player $i$ wins a game of $K$ rounds?**

Note:

I know how to solve the problem using conditional probability: for an example, there are 3 players: $n_1=3, n_2=2, n_3=5$ and 2 rounds. The probability that the first player wins $P_1=P(A) + P(B)$ where $A$ *- the first and the second players are winners*, $B$ *- the first and the third players are winners*.

Let's say $Q_p^r$  means the fact that the $p$ player's card is drawn at the $r$ round

Then $P(A)=P(Q_1^1)\cdot P(Q_2^2 | Q_1^1) + P(Q_2^1)\cdot P(Q_1^2 | Q_2^1) = \frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{7} + \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{8}\approx0.1607$

$P(B)=P(Q_1^1)\cdot P(Q_3^2 | Q_1^1) + P(Q_3^1)\cdot P(Q_1^2 | Q_3^1) = \frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{5}{7} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{5}\approx0.5143$

So, $P_1 = P(A) + P(B) \approx0.6749$

It is easy in this case, but how to solve the problem in general? What if $M$ and $K$ are much larger? Maybe there is a pretty elegant solution?

Comment: One slight simplification: You can stop as soon as the player in question does win, so $P_1 = P(Q_1^1) + P(Q_2^1) \cdot P(Q_1^2|Q_2^1) + P(Q_3^1) \cdot P(Q_1^2|Q_3^1)$. I don't see another way to do it, and the formulae don't seem to simplify much, at least in the most general case.

Comment: Clarification requested: "What is the probability that a player $i$ wins a game of $K$ rounds?" In your example, where exactly $2$ rounds were played, you construed Player-1 to be *the winner* even though he was only *tied for first*.  Is that your intention, that player $(i)$ either wins outright, or is tied for first ?

Comment: For what it's worth, I originally posted several comments, suggesting that Inclusion-Exclusion was the way to go.  There were so many lengthy comments that I deleted them, and instead *began* posting an **answer** that used Inclusion-Exclusion.  However, the Math was so ugly, that I gave up.  For example, assume that the player who wins is player $(M)$.  Further assume that you are examining the specific situation where player $M$ wins exactly $(r)$ games.  Further assume that you are also examining the situation where player $(1)$, for example wins more than $(r)$ games.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then, player $(1)$ can win any number of games between $(r + 1)$ and $\min(K - r, n_1)$, inclusive.  That means that I had to break up the case where player $(1)$ wins more than $(r)$ games into a group of sub-cases.  For me, this *added ugliness* was the breaking point, so I abandoned the approach.  Someone else may be able to make Inclusion-Exclusion (or some other appproach) work with less ugliness.